# TV Show - Mission: Reading or Reading Mission

Tags: story-identification, tv, educational

I'm trying to find information about a TV show, or perhaps a segment from a TV show. I believe it was called Mission: Reading, or Reading Mission. It was a live-action kids educational TV show circa the 1990s, either American or Canadian. I only saw one episode of it. It featured a boy and a girl on a very Great Value Starship Enterprise-looking space ship. I believe the ship had an AI, and a teleporter that looked like a barber pole which they used by spinning around.

Comment: Mission Reading is listed as a show broadcast by ABC and produced by TV Ontario. There's no good info on wikipedia about it though; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programs_broadcast_by_ABC_Television

Comment: https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0636812/bio

Comment: Described as a "comedy-educational" series; http://archivesfa.library.yorku.ca/fonds/ON00370-f0000572.htm

Answer (score 3):

I'm going through an old vhs tape from around 1995 and it has 2 episodes of the show on it. The show stars Zack Ward (the bully with the fox hat from "A Christmas Story") and each episode runs only 15 minutes long. Like you said, it's an educational TV show about 2 teenagers- a boy (Zack Ward) and a blonde girl- on a spaceship (but wearing typical 90s attire) and they have sketches/ dream sequences that take place other places. The first episode I have has them imagining that they are 1940's detectives, and the second has them imagining that they're wrestlers in costumes with capes and eye masks. I'm surprised that the show isn't even listed on imdb. According to the end credits, the show is from 1992. I recorded it off of the (defunct) cable channel plex. I was actually recording the Kim Cattrall TV movie "The Gossip Columnist", and this aired right after it. I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  There's some useful information here; can you confirm the form of the name of the show?

Comment: I have found some references to Zack Ward being in a show named Mission Reading, maybe on TVO, produced by Allan Novak?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Allan Novak's [IMDb bio](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0636812/bio) mentions him as the director of "Mission Reading (TVO)"

Comment: And... I didn't read the prior comment on the question. TVO indeed matches to TV Ontario. This looks to likely be the answer, but it seems to be a largely lost bit of media. If Peter were to upload the content of his tapes to YouTube and/or The Internet Archive, it might help keeping this from being lost forever.